# BodePlot with magnitude in db or log scale

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale, control-systems

I have to plot a `BodePlot` with magnitude in db or log, but i could not find the option for setting the magnitude scale.

```
BodePlot[
    mytf,
    GridLines -> Automatic,
    PlotLabel -> {"Magnitude Plot", "Phase Plot"},
    MagnitudeDisplay -> Absolute
    ]
```

But apparently `MagnitudeDisplay -> AbsoluteValues / Decibels` is not an option for bodeplot.
i tried also the option `ScalingFunctions->{{magfreqscale,magscale},{phasefreqscale,phasescale}}` setting `ScalingFunctions -> {{"Log10", "Log10"}, {"Log10", "Degree"}}` but again, the command is not valid.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the option `ScalingFunctions`:

[BodePlot >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BodePlot.html):
[image]

```
BodePlot[TransferFunctionModel[{{{20}}, 20 + s}, s], 
  GridLines -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> {"Magnitude Plot", "Phase Plot"}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {{Automatic, "Absolute"}, {Automatic, "Radian"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: but in this case, the magnitude scale is linear in the y-axis. I would like to have a log-log plot instead. (log scale not only in the x-axis)

Comment: @Betelgeuse, the only options for the vertical scale are `"dB"` and `"Absolute"`; so I think  the only way to get what you want is post-processing the output to rescale the vertical coordinates of lines.

Comment: Indeed, I don't see any other options..

Comment: @Betelgeuse are you aware that dB are logarithmic?

Comment: @Gladaed, yes, I'm preparing some materials for students and their textbook displays the bode plot in log scale. I just wanted to show them both to let them understand.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is what you are looking for. It is a bit of a hack, and I think what you want should be an accepted value for `ScalingFunctions`.

```
bp = BodePlot[100/(s + 1)];
ft = FrameTicks /. 
     Cases[bp[[1, 1, 1]], HoldPattern[Rule][FrameTicks, x_], Infinity];
ft[[1, 1]] = ft[[1, 1]] /. {t_, v_} :> {t, v/20.};
bp[[1, 1, 1]] = Show[bp[[1, 1, 1]], FrameTicks -> ft];
bp
```

[image]